# Merge columns of distinct SQL queries

Tags: sql, database, exception

I have three distinct SQL queries which need to be merged.(shown here are just two).

I tried to put one query in the FROM Clause in parenthesis example given.

I am trying to list user with last date of his order and in the same time I want to list the number of orders, it would work but because of the `GROUP BY` I get an error:

> Subquery must return only one column

and `UNION` does not work because of

> Each UNION query must have the same number of columns

So the problem is simple: I just want to merge to results from two queries together into one result set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT order.ordner_nr,name,oDate,             

(
SELECT  
   order_nr, COUNT(*) as ammountOrders
FROM
     order
GROUP BY    -- Error occurs 
   order_nr
)



FROM user
INNER JOIN order
using (order_nr)
where (order_nr, oDate) in  
    (select order_nr, max(oDate)
     from order group by order_nr)
```

I tried UNION like i said above and all sorts of things and I don't know what to do also I'm a noob in SQL

Comment: What exacty do you want to show in your result rows? The user name, the user's total number of orders, and the user's last order date and number? What is your DBMS? (Always tag your SQL request with your DBMS in order to get answers that work for you.)

Comment: If you are a beginner with SQL, CTEs (`WITH` clauses) can be helpful. Select all users' first orders in one CTE, select all users's order counts in another CTE. Then in the main query select from users and join the two CTEs to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subqueries can only return scalar values like your count see query below,

Of you nned more column you need to join the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT order.ordner_nr,name,oDate,             
(
SELECT  
   COUNT(*) 
FROM
     order o1
WHERE
   o1.order_nr = order.order_nr
) as ammountOrders
FROM user
INNER JOIN order
using (order_nr)
where (order_nr, oDate) in  
    (select order_nr, max(oDate)
     from order group by order_nr)
```

Comment: but this counts every order number... there are different multiple order numbers and i need to count each of them

Comment: can you provide a dbfidlle, it is hard bto comprehend without seeing structure and data

Comment: sorry dont know what this is ... i just need to know how you can get the result of 2 queries into one table thats all

Comment: go to the page https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30 and add yor tables with data, as i don't know your structure, i can't tell you exactly what to do . in general make a select query that gives you all the wanted rows make a Count(*) instead of coluumns and change the where clause to link with the outer from clause